# PHP contact form with hidden field not working

Tags: php, forms, conditional-statements

I have two different contact forms on a site that I'm trying to use the same php file to process.  I would like to use this code on one section of the code with a "1" being the first forms hidden field value, and a "2" being the second form's hidden field value.

```
if ($_POST['process']=='1'){}
```

No matter what I do, I can't get this code to work.  I've tried removing the code above, and the contact form submits just fine.  Another thing I tried was changing the hidden value to a text field to verify that there was actually a value being displayed, which there was.  i've also included the 'process' hidden field value as a variable and sent it in an e-mail, which is where things seemed to get weird for me.  The value of that variable comes across blank in an e-mail.  What am I doing wrong here?  Here is my code:

```
 if(!$_POST) exit;
    function remove_non_numeric($string) {
    return preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $string);
    }

    function isEmail($email) {
    return preg_match("/^(?!.{255,})(?!.{65,}@)([!#-'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+)(?>\.(?1))*@(?!.*[^.]        {64,})(?>[a-z0-9](?>[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.){1,126}[a-z]{2,6}$/iD", $email);
    }
    if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

    if ($_POST['process']=='1'){

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone    = remove_non_numeric($_POST['phone']);
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];
$process  = $_POST['process'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have entered an invalid e-mail address, please try again.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter the verification number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}

$address = "myemail@email.com";
$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';
$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name. Their message is below." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$process\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";



$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been sent.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';
}
}
```

I've removed the second bit of code that would process the other form, for the sake of simplicity, but hopefully you can see what I'm attempting to do.  If the hidden field called "process" has a value of "1", then process this code.  If it had a value of 2, I would want it to process the other code instead.

here's the html portion of the code:

```
<div id="contact">

            <div id="message"></div>

            <form method="post" action="http://s423839726.onlinehome.us/franklinvineyard/contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

            <fieldset>

            <input type="text" name="process" id="process" size="4" value="1" />

            <label for="name">Your Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" />

            <br />
            <label for="email">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />

            <br />
            <label for="phone">Phone<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" size="30" value="" />


            <br />
            <label for="comments">Comments<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="15" id="comments" style="width: 350px;"></textarea>

            <label>Are you human?<span class="required">*</span></label>

            <label class="accesskey" for="verify">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 + 1 =</label>
            <input class="accesskey" name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="4" value="" style="width: 30px;" /><br /><br />

            <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

            </fieldset>

            </form>
        </div><!--end contact-->
```

there is also some jquery that processes the form...Could this be the problem?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#message').hide();

          $('#submit')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');
     if($('#process').val()=='1'){
        $.post(action, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            comments: $('#comments').val(),
            verify: $('#verify').val()
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();
                                                                      });
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') !== null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

            }
        );
    else{
        $.post(action, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            friend: $('#friend').val(),
            search: $('#search').val(),
            signage: $('#signage').val(),
            vineyard: $('#vineyard').val(),
            newspaper: $('#newspaper').val(),
            other: $('#other').val(),
            comments1: $('#comments-survey1').val(),
            comments2: $('#comments-survey2').val(),
            comments3: $('#comments-survey3').val(),
            verify: $('#verify').val()
        },
        function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();
                                                                      });
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') !== null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

            }
        );

        });

        return false;
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Show your HTML Part also

Comment: Add `echo $_POST['process'];` at different parts of your code and have a look if the values is changing somewhere.

Comment: Please send your HTML with the form too

Comment: You can use print_r($_POST); to print the whole array of POST variables. Check then whether the 'process' variable is set correctly.

Comment: Alternatively you can edit the form action URL like this: `http://s423839726.onlinehome.us/franklinvineyard/contact.php?process=1` and then use `$_GET['process']==1` to check.

Comment: I used print_r and it came back with: Array ( [name] => Jon Mason [email] => myemail@email.com [phone] => 555-555-5555 [comments] => test [verify] => 4 ).  Its totally ignoring the "hidden" field

Comment: Does it work when you change the hidden field to a text field? Your notes isn't clear

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, I originally had it as a hidden field, but as of right now, I've just changed it to a text field to verify that it was actually there when the page loads, which it is.  Then, I included the value of that field as a variable, and changed the e-mail message of the contact form so that instead of sending the comments, it sends the value of the 'process' field.  The e-mail sends fine, but the field displays as blank.  Somewhere along the way its getting removed.

Comment: Can you post a version of the code that is not working? The HTML section you have posted is working fine you say.

Comment: the current version of the code above is not working.  If I change the text field to a hidden field, it still doesn't work.  The only way I've gotten the code above to work is by commenting out or removing the if ($_POST['process']=='1'){} code entirely.

Comment: @user1476992 Where in your source code have you inserted `print_r`? Have you put it in different places to see if the values are changing during execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are intercepting your submit in javascript and not passing all your form fields to the form handler. To correct it, replace this:

```
$.post(action, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            comments: $('#comments').val(),
            verify: $('#verify').val()
        },
```

with this:

```
$.post(action, $('#contactform').serialize(),
```

Comment: This was a huge help.  Can't thank you enough!  I've been banging my head against a wall for too long with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple you can test using `if($_REQUEST['process']==1)` as any `POST` or `GET` parameter can be access via `REQUEST`

Comment: His HTML says `<form method="post" ...`

Comment: @user1476992 Did you see the `var_dump($_POST)` ?. Just add the line `var_dump($_POST); exit(); ` for sake of testing

Comment: yes, in effect that would be the same as print_r?  Here is the output: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Test" ["email"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" ["phone"]=> string(12) "615-555-5555" ["comments"]=> string(4) "test" ["verify"]=> string(1) "4" }

Comment: FYI...i added var_dump($_POST['process']); exit(); to the code and the value returned NULL.  It shouldn't be null, right?